# Why isn't my Mobile Menu opening when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am trying to make a mobile menu for a responsive webpage. When I try to click my mobile menu icon, the dropdown section doesn't appear and nothing happens. I feel like my code is correct and have combed through it multiple times but I have hit a dead-end. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am still kind of new to HTML/CSS/JS

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>The Panel Guys</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">The Panel Guys</a>
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Home </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="about.html" class="navbar__links"> About </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item"> 
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Gallery </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__btn">
            <a href="/" class="button"> Contact </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #fff;
        
        
    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5 ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: black;
    }

    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }

    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

And JS:

```
const menu = document.querySelector("#mobile=menu");
const menuLinks = document.querySelector(".navbar__menu");

menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menu.classList.toggle("is-active");
  menuLinks.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Comment: In your JS code, you are calling with the wrong id(#mobile=menu). The original id is (#mobile-menu)

Comment: Wow I feel like such an idiot, it was so simple!. Thank you so much man you've saved me a massive headache

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled the id name of the menu in app.js. As per your code, the id is "#mobile-menu" and not "#mobile=menu" you putted = instead of -.

**The updated version of the app.js: **

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#mobile-menu"); #changed the #mobile=menu -> #mobile-menu
const menuLinks = document.querySelector(".navbar__menu");

menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menu.classList.toggle("is-active");
  menuLinks.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `#mobile=menu` to `#mobile-menu` in js

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#mobile-menu");
const menuLinks = document.querySelector(".navbar__menu");

menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menu.classList.toggle("is-active");
  menuLinks.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #fff;
        
        
    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5 ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: black;
    }

    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }

    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>The Panel Guys</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">The Panel Guys</a>
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Home </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="about.html" class="navbar__links"> About </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item"> 
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Gallery </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__btn">
            <a href="/" class="button"> Contact </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```